# PHP IF statement with four conditions

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I would like to examine four conditions in an php if statement? e.g.

```
If ((a == 1 || 2 || 3) && (b == 1 || 2 || 3) && (c == 1 || 2 || 3) && (d == 1 || 2 || 3)) {

    .... Execute query 

}
```

This is what I am using in my code thus far:

```
<?php


include 'dbconnect.php';


//check if variable is set

if ( isset($_POST['beaches'], $_POST['species']) && !empty($_POST['beaches'] && !empty($_POST['species']))) {
    $beachid = strtolower($_POST['beaches']); 

    echo '<br>';
    $speciesid = strtolower($_POST['species']);
    echo '<br>';
    //$fishmethodid = strtolower($_POST['fish_method']); 
    echo '<br>';
//if ( isset($_POST['species']) && !empty($_POST['species'])) {
//  echo  $speciesid = $_POST['species'];


//if ( isset($_POST['fish_method']) && !empty($_POST['fish_method'])) {
//  echo  $fishmethodid = $_POST['fish_method'];

// die();

//query begins

    if ($beachid == '1' || $beachid == '2' || $beachid == '3'|| $beachid == '4'|| $beachid == '5' || $beachid == '6' || $beachid == '7' || $beachid == '8' || $beachid == '9' || $beachid == '10' || $beachid == '11' || $beachid == '13' || $beachid == '14' || $beachid == '15' || $beachid == '16' || $beachid == '17' || $beachid == '18' || $beachid == '19' || $beachid == '20' || $beachid == '21' || $beachid == '22' && ($speciesid == '1' || $speciesid == '2' || $speciesid == '3' || $speciesid == '4' || $speciesid == '5' || $speciesid == '6' || $speciesid == '7')) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `beach`.`beach_description`, `species_description`, `fishmethod`.`fishmet_description`, `weight`, `price`, `date`
                    FROM `returnlanded` 
                    INNER JOIN `beach` ON `returnlanded`.`beachid` = `beach`.`beach_id`
                     INNER JOIN `species` ON `returnlanded`.`speciesid` = `species`.`species_id`
                    INNER JOIN `fishmethod` ON `returnlanded`.`fishmethodid` = `fishmethod`.`fishmet_id`
                     WHERE `returnlanded`.`beachid`='$beachid' AND `returnlanded`.`speciesid`='$speciesid'");//" ORDER BY returnlanded.`id` ";


        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {

            $resp["catch"] = array();

                while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $weight = $query_row['weight'];
                    $price = $query_row['price'];
                    $fishmethodid = $query_row['fishmet_description'];
                    $date = $query_row ['date'];

                    $catch = array();
                    $catch["$beachid"] = $query_row['beach_description'];
                    $catch["$speciesid"] = $query_row['species_description'];
                    $catch["$fishmethodid"] = $query_row['fishmet_description'];
                    $catch["$weight"] = $query_row['weight'];
                    $catch["$price"] = $query_row['price'];
                    $catch["$date"] = $query_row['date'];


                    array_push($resp["catch"], $catch);



                }

    //if successful
    $resp["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($resp);
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Date</th><th>Location</th><th>Fish Species</th><th>Fishing Method (Gear)</th><th>Weight (lbs)</th><th>Price($)</th>";
     echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>".$catch["$date"]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$catch["$beachid"]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$catch["$speciesid"]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$catch["$fishmethodid"]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$catch["$weight"]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$catch["$price"]."</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
             echo "</table>";
            echo'<br>';
} else {

    $resp["success"] = 0;
    $resp["display"] = "No data found";
    json_encode($resp);
    echo '<br>';
    echo "No results found for your search";
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';

        }
    }
    }       




include 'templates/searchagain.php';
include 'templates/footer.php';

 ?>
```

However the query only works when I use up to two conditions ($speciesid and $beachid). I did some research but I am not finding anything to accommodate the four conditions. I would like to include $fishmethodid and $date in the if-statement.

Is it possible that someone can help please?

Comment: when you check for beachid and speciesid you can parse them into integers and just check to see if it is less than 22 and 7. i.e : if( (beachid < 22) && (speciesid < 7) )

Comment: you might be missing one or two brackets too, like between `...$beachid == '22' && ($speciesid == '1'...`

Comment: There is no technical limit on the number of conditions in an `if` statement. But, as has been mentioned here, there are other control structures that might be easier to read and maintain. Check into a `switch` statement, or `in_array`. As for your code here, if it isn't working as you expect it to, the problem is not with the number of conditionals in the `if` statement, but rather the way they are arranged. Check your syntax! It isn't required that all the conditions be on the same line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(a == 1 || 2 || 3)
```

This kind of structure is incorrect, because it will evaluate `1 || 2 || 3` (Which is `true`, because at least one... well, *all* of the operands are truthy).

Instead, try this:

```
in_array($a,range(1,3))
```

Comment: thank you!... only problem I have now is that only one result is displaying in the output table when I query rows with the same values.. however the json output displays all results

Answer (score 0):

WOW!  Glad you aren't checking between 1 and 100. How about:

```
if ($beachid >= 1 && $beachid <= 22 && $speciesid >= 1 && $speciesid <= 7) {
```

This might read better:

```
if ( ($beachid >= 1 && $beachid <= 22) && ($speciesid >= 1 && $speciesid <= 7) ) {
```

Or you can simplify somewhat:

```
if ( ($beachid > 0 && $beachid < 23) && ($speciesid > 0 && $speciesid < 8) ) {
```